# What is "dev-mapper-fedora\x2dRoot.device"

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, systemd

I have an laptop with i7 processor on which I use Fedora 22. Initially few weeks ago It had startup time of `2min 41sec` as provided by `systemd-analyze`.
After following several articles and answers on here, on SO, and arch wiki, I have managed to bring it to between "29.790s to 44.890s". Largest time is taken by userspace but almost all of the userspace time is consumed by **`"dev-mapper-fedora\x2dRoot.device"`** . Here is my stats from this startup.

`[Abhinav@abhinav-fed22 ~] $ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 4.382s (firmware) + 4.612s (loader) + 3.367s (kernel) + 12.856s (initrd) + 19.671s (userspace) = 44.890s
[Abhinav@abhinav-fed22 ~] $ systemd-analyze blame
         19.124s dev-mapper-fedora\x2dRoot.device
          9.048s systemd-fsck-root.service
          3.972s accounts-daemon.service
          3.968s systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-fedora\x2dHome.service
          3.467s packagekit.service
          3.217s systemd-journald.service
          2.986s systemd-modules-load.service
          2.039s NetworkManager.service
          1.977s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.888s plymouth-start.service
          1.789s systemd-binfmt.service
          1.728s lvm2-pvscan@8:3.service
          1.692s ModemManager.service
          1.434s colord.service
          1.384s fedora-readonly.service
          1.317s systemd-logind.service`

As you can see, Out of 19.671s taken by userspace, 19.124s is consumed by only one process, dev-mapper-fedora\x2dRoot.device.
Q: What is this process? Google search reviled nothing good.
Q: How do I bring this under control?

Comment: It's one of your logical volumes. I guess the one used for your root filesystem. The next one down, systemd-fsck-root, seems to have taken a while. Maybe it did a more thorough check during that boot. Does it normally take that long?

Comment: @LukeDixon Yes, It takes this long. Earlier, NetworkManager-wait-online was the one which took most time. Now this. Usually I get 32-35 sec. But I have seen 29 sec and like this morning, 44 sec. Current startup took 38 sec. I didn't bother much earlier, but now it has been pointed that it is very large for i7 processor.